# TCL load error can't load file libfoo.so

Tags: tcl

I am trying to load a simple TCL extension, but I keep getting the following error:

```
couldn't load file "libfoo.so": ld.so.1: tclsh8.4_64: fatal: libfoo.so: open failed: No such file or directory
```

I am using the example from [TCL man page](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/load.htm)
but I am not sure what I doing wrong here. I am compiling the library on Solaris using:

```
cc -KPIC -c -I/opt/external/tcl-8.5.8/include foo.c
cc -shared -R/opt/external/tcl-8.5.8/i386/lib -L/opt/external/tcl-8.5.8/i386/lib -o libfoo.so foo.o
```

Could someone please advise on how to debug the issue?

Comment: Glad to see my example is helping someone.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here.

1. The filename for the library that you pass to `load` should probably have a directory separator in it. When a directory separator is present, that suppresses the operating system's search for the library, which is how you want things to be because you already know where it is.
2. You appear to be trying to `load` the library into an older version of Tcl than it was linked against. (You might also be trying to load a 32-bit build into a 64-bit executable.) That's *vanishingly* unlikely to work. Link against the oldest version of Tcl that you wish to support; when developing, that's best done by linking against the exact version of Tcl that you are going to load into, and for production you should see the [Tcl_InitStubs](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclLib/InitStubs.htm) manpage for details.

Comment: Note that I've linked to the 8.6 version of the manpage only because the formatting is better in it. The content is the same in 8.5 and 8.4 too, but the automatically-generated page layout is buggier.

Comment: Thanks Donal, once I specified the full path the error went away. Also, I fixed the libraries that I was using.